# cakePHP 2.x redirecting

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

First link redirects to posts, as "localhost/posts", but the other one doesn't redirect to "localhost/albus", but instead to "localhost/app/webroot/albums/"

And yes the album has it's index page

The code:

```
<?php
    echo '<li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>';
?> 
<?php 
    echo '<li><a href="/albums">albums</a></li>';
?>
```

Comment: do you have any `albumsController`? I think you have `postController` and `albums` is a folder inside `webroot`?

Comment: yes I have albumsController, I have both controllers. I don't have an albums folder in webroot

Comment: Do you add any route against albums ??

Comment: nope, http://prntscr.com/f05jtu

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any redirects that are not done by the CakePHP application, i. e. in your `.htaccess` files.

Try if specifying a `RewriteBase` in the `.htaccess` works.

**/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase    /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain HTMLyou can use Cakephp syntax which will help you to redirect on which action you have to redirect.

According to your code that should work but you have to define some rules in you virtual host.
Simple solution use cake php syntax,

For example :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Album List'), array(
 'controller' => 'alubms', 
 'action' => 'index'),
 array('title'=>'<title>','class' => <class_if_any>));
?>
```

Comment: im not quite sure how to implement that in this case

Comment: <?php
                if(AuthComponent::user()) {
                    echo '<li><a href="/albums/">albums</a></li>';
                } else {        
                    echo '';
                }
            ?>

Comment: but the thing is why is my localhost/posts working, but localhost/albums is not